# Render Camera Preview onto SurfaceTexture while using WebRTC

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-camera, webrtc, google-cardboard

I'm building an Augmented Reality app (using Google Cardboard) that uses WebRTC (I'm using pristine.io's compiled sources) to stream the camera preview to a webclient. The user should be able to see "through" the camera.

My Problem is: to enable the user to see through the camera, I need to render the camera preview onto a `SurfaceTexture` (which is used for the Virtual Reality view), using an instance of `camera`. This by itself is easy (and already done), but WebRTC is already creating an instance of `camera` (in a class called `VideoCapturerAndroid`) and two of those at the same time are obviously not working. Also, `VideoCapturerAndroid` has a private constructor (and is offering a factory method) and no Getter for the camera field. Because of this, I can't get the field to set the Preview Texture...

I tried to find the source Code to be able to simply change that class (e.g. creating a Getter), but with no success.
I also thought about creating a `GLSurfaceView.Renderer` to render the `GLSurfaceView`, on which the WebRTC Library is drawing, to a `SurfaceTexture` (explained here: https://coderwall.com/p/6koh_g/rendering-any-android-view-directly-to-an-opengl-texture), but the Renderer is already getting set in `VideoRendererGui` and according to the docs, you can only set the Renderer of a View once.

Does anyone have an idea how I can access the camera field in `VideoCapturerAndroid` or get the preview data elsewhere to render it onto the `SurfaceTexture`?

Comment: did you find a way out ?

Comment: Maybe try android reflection?